# from_json is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have following code :-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
val ds = df.select(from_json($"value" cast "string", schema)).as[event]
```

but it gives an error

```
value from_json is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.functions
```

Using this dependency :-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `from_json` was introduced in 2.1.0 I believe

Comment: getting this error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.checkValue(Lscala/Function1;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/internal/config/TypedConfigBuilder;
 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<clinit>(SQLConf.scala)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<init>(StaticSQLConf.scala:31)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<clinit>(StaticSQLConf.scala)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:935)

Comment: All your dependencies must be compatible with Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.11 otherwise you'll keep getting ClassNotFound and MethodNotFound errors

Comment: <dependency><groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId><artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId><version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>  Using these dependencies

Comment: Your `spark-core` and `spark-streaming` is still on version 2.0.0. please update those. Also, please refrain from commenting more on this post as this is off-topic as per the asked question.

Comment: ok I got it. Thanks for the support